# Method "onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item,LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container)" is never used

Tags: java, android

I am using onOptionsItemSelected method for filter my listviewes but after declared that method i got method never used exception,I dont know how to use this method.please correct my code.

my programming code is below,

```
   //I am getting exception here

        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item,LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container) {
        Log.d("onOptionsItemSelected", "yes");
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.all:
                displayEventInvitationList(inflater,container);
                return true;
            case R.id.event:
                displayEventList();
                return true;
            case R.id.invitation:
                displayInvitationList();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }

    }
        //method defined here
        public View displayEventInvitationList(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chatwindow_tab, container, false);
        sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        final UserMO userMO = dbHelper.getRingeeUserData(1);
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<EventMO>>() {
            @Override
            protected List<EventMO> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                eventMOs = gson.fromJson(eventDelegates.getAllEventFromUser(userMO, context), new TypeToken<List<EventMO>>() {
                }.getType());
                invitationMOs = gson.fromJson(eventDelegates.getAllEventForUser(userMO, context), new TypeToken<List<EventMO>>() {
                }.getType());
                List<EventMO> groupEventInvitesList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (EventMO eventMO : eventMOs) {
                    groupEventInvitesList.add(eventMO);

                }
                for (EventMO eventMO : invitationMOs) {
                    groupEventInvitesList.add(eventMO);

                }

                return groupEventInvitesList;

            }
```

Comment: You have to override this method....have You just put it inside?

Comment: please suggest me the code ..

Comment: what are You using Eclipse or Android Studio? No matter how, You have to set @Override annotation above the method....usually You can override in Android Studio with "Menu-->Refactor->Generate->Override method", and then select onOptionsItemSelected from the list...

Comment: i am using that in android studio

Answer (score 2):

> i got method never used exception

First, that is a warning, not an exception.

Second, it is never used, because nobody calls it.

Perhaps you are looking to implement [`onOptionsItemSelected()` on a `Fragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onOptionsItemSelected%28android.view.MenuItem%29), which has a different method signature. Or, if this is an activity, it too [offers `onOptionsItemSelected()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected%28android.view.MenuItem%29), but with a different signature. If you delete the `LayoutInflater inflater` and `ViewGroup container` parameters, you may have better luck.

Answer (score 0):

`onOptionsItemSelected` is a method of `Activity` (or of a `Fragment`).
You have deifned it somewhere else.
Cut your method from where you defined it and paste it inside your activity (or Fragment) that is one level up - just before the last closing }